# Is it possible to send update via twitter api to a specific user, even if user are offline, with no time limit?

Tags: api, twitter

If we have an application which need to:
-> ask user to authenticate using twitter (oAuth) in order to get the access token
-> store the token and send message to the user even if he is disconnected from twitter

My question is:
Is it possible to send update via twitter api to a specific user, even if user are offline, with no time limit?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my own question.

The OAuth token seems to never expire. It means that you can catch token for a user, then store it and use it for sending tweet to the user even if user is not connected. It works.